# Find the min max and average of one column of data in python

Tags: python

I have a set of data that looks like this

> 201206040210 -3461.00000000 -8134.00000000 -4514.00000000
>   -4394.00000000 0 201206040211 -3580.00000000 -7967.00000000 -4614.00000000 -7876.00000000 0 201206040212 -3031.00000000 -9989.00000000 -9989.00000000 -3419.00000000 0 201206040213 -1199.00000000 -6961.00000000 -3798.00000000 -5822.00000000 0 201206040214 -2940.00000000 -5524.00000000 -5492.00000000
>   -3394.00000000 0

I want to take the second to last column and find the min, max, and average. 
Im a little confused on how to use split when the columns are delimited by a space and -. 
i Figure once i do that i can use min() and max function. I have written a shell script to do the same here

```
#!/bin/ksh
awk '{print substr($5,2);}' data' > /data1
sort -n data1 > data2
tail -1 data2
head -1 data2
awk '{sum+=$1} END {print "average = ",sum/NR}' data2
```

Im just not sure how to do this in python. Thanks

EDIT: Decided to use numpy to do this.

Comment: Are you sure that the `-` is a delimiter and not a negative sign?

Comment: For future reference: if you change your mind about a question, then don't delete the question. Otherwise, future readers looking at this thread won't know what the answers refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open("filename") as f:    
    cols = [float(row.split("-")[-2]) for row in f.readlines()]
print min(cols), max(cols), sum(cols) / len(cols)
```

Comment: are you sure `cols` is columns, not rows?

Comment: cols is only one column ... the 2nd to last one

Comment: hm for some reason I am getting a SyntaxError
    File "<stdin>", line 1
        with  open("/tmp/$PLG620120604") as f: 
                 ^

Comment: @user1440194: what version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
with open('rows.txt', 'r') as f:
    col=[float(row.split("-")[-2]) for row in f]

print 'min: {} max: {} avg: {}'.format(min(col),max(col),sum(col)/float(len(col)))
```

Output:

```
min: 3798.0 max: 9989.0 avg: 5681.4
```

If you want to read stdin, this:

```
import sys

col=[float(row.split("-")[-2]) for row in sys.stdin]

print 'min: {} max: {} avg: {}'.format(min(col),max(col),sum(col)/float(len(col)))
```

will read the stdin text to do the same thing.